# MPI derived datatype for Eigen Array

Tags: c++, types, mpi, eigen

I am working on a project where I created a class using Eigen's Array like this

```
class Cartesian{
   public:
      double x() const { return r_(0); }
      double y() const { return r_(1); }
      double z() const { return r_(2); }
   private:
      Eigen::Array3d r_; 
 }

 Eigen::Array<Cartesian, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> Cart_Array(10);
```

So now I want to send Cart_Array using MPI_Send from Proc 0 to Proc 1. What's the best way to do it? I want to create a derived MPI datatype; e.g., Cart_Type, and then send it as

```
 MPI_Send(&Cart_Array, 10, Cart_Type, 1, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD).
```

I know how to create MPI derived types for simple things using MPI_Type_create_struct, etc. But I don't know how to do it for the case I showed. Please show me. If possible, I would want to avoid other libraries such as Boost.

EDITS:

I asked this question because I wanted to avoid using the serialization approach. And that's because this is part of a large program that emphasizes efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like below. Just serialise one or many `Cartesian` into vector of doubles, send and receive those doubles and deserialise. I hope that this compiles, cause I just typed this down on a machine without MPI. I don't have Eigen installed, but you get the idea.

```
class Cartesian{
public:
  double x() const { return r_(0); }
  double y() const { return r_(1); }
  double z() const { return r_(2); }
  std::vector<double> const& r() const { return r_; };
  Cartesian* operator=(std::vector<double> const& r) {r_ = r;} 
private:
  std::vector<double> r_;
  //Eigen::Array3d r_; 
};

// Send vector of Cartesian
void sendData(std::vector<Cartesian> const& v) {
  std::vector<double> data;
  for (auto const& i : v) {
    data.insert(data.end(), v.r().begin(), v.r().end());
  }
  MPI_Send(data.begin(), data.size(), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

// Receive vector of Cartesian
std::vector<Cartesian> recvData() {

  int n;
  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Probe(0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); // Incoming?
  MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_INT, &n); // Number of incoming

  std::vector<Cartesian> v;
  if (n>0) {
    std::vector<double>(n);
    MPI_Recv(n.begin(), n, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    v.resize(n/3);
    int i = 0;
    for (auto i : v) {
      i.r(*b.begin()+3*i);
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return v;

}

int main() {

  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  int size, rank;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

  std::vector<Cartesian> data;
  if (rank == 0) {
    data.resize(1000);
    sendData(data);
  } else {
    data = recvData();
  }

  MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually used serialization in my previous version of the code, but it involves copying and moving data. I want to use derived datatype to hope that it might be more efficient, since the code I showed is part of a large High Performance Computation program.  Any particular reason why you use std::vector instead of Eigen, besides you don't have it?

Comment: What network fabric are you using? If you are not on Infiniband don't even start thinking down that route. Also, if I were you, I'd profile the code and find out, if you are not optimising 0.001%. I highly doubt that compared to the networking and computation time, you will be able to put a value on the serialisation.

Comment: I use the code on several platforms, some of them use Infiniband. Thanks for your help.